# How to visualize aggregation, composition in Visual Studio class diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to create and visualize Aggregation, Composition, dependency in Visual Studio Class Diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The class diagram give you a view of a single model.
To show the whole model you can do this in a modeling project.